# How to create an info icon with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I so far failed to create what is colloquially called an "info icon" with wxPython. An icon with some sort of 'i' image that shows a large tooltip on hover.

I can add a `wx.StaticBitmap` for the image but it ignores all `SetToolTipString` or `SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip())` calls. OR I can add a large tool tip to a `wx.StaticText` as shown below.

[image]
Ignore that the icon doesn't have the correct size yet.

Needless to say that eventually the tooltip needs a background color that is different from the panel background color (not the focus here). I can't use `wx.adv.RichToolTip` because I'm on wxPython 3.0.2.0 osx-cocoa.

What is a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is show a tooltip when the image is moused over, then you need to bind your instance of the `wx.StaticBitmap` to `EVT_MOTION`:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_WARNING)
        self.image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=bmp)

        self.image.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_mouse_over)

    def on_mouse_over(self, event):
        self.image.SetToolTipString('BLAH BLAH BLAH')


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Icon Mouser')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I run this code, I get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think the issue is that on osx-cocoa the `StaticBitmap` is refusing the `SetToolTipString` string. As I'm not an user of that OS, I can't comment one way or the other.

Comment: That's what I thought as well at first. Of course I tried that before I posted this question. Turns out that if you set it in the `wx.EVT_MOTION` event handler it _does_ work.

Comment: You didn't customize the tooltip, did you? How come it's got round corners and a black background? Are those system settings wxPython relies upon?
 By coincidence I found out about `wx.PopupTransientWindow`. I could display an instance of it that looks like a rich tooltip (as seen in the demo) on mouse over. It might be tricky to find the right event to kill it when the mouse isn't on the "trigger image" any more.

Comment: wxPython uses the native widget whenever possible, so this tooltip is probably the native one used in Xubuntu 14.04. You could bind `EVT_MOTION` to the panel in addition to the image widget. When the motion event is fired for the panel, you could check for the transient windows existence and destroy it if it exists.

Comment: I settled eventually for `EVT_MOTION` and a custom HTML-enabled tooltip that supports hyperlinks: https://frightanic.com/software-development/create-an-info-icon-with-wxpython/

Answer (score 2):

If you create a button with an ID of `wx.ID_HELP` then you'll get the stock help button for the platform, if it has one. Then you can do whatever you want with it like any button. Assign a tooltip, do something in the `EVT_BUTTON` event, etc. See the [StockButtons sample in the demo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/StockButtons.py). If the stock image or label doesn't meet your needs then you can probably just use a wx.BitmapButton to show the image you want and still have the standard tooltip support.

Something else you may want to look into is the [ContextHelp sample in the demo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/ContextHelp.py). It shows how to use a `wx.ContextHelpButton` which, when clicked, puts the application into context-help mode. A popup tip window will then be shown for whatever widget is clicked on next.  Not quite what you are asking for, but it might be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks, I added links to the samples, will study them. Apart from that, same feedback as for @rolf-of-saxony... the UX semantics of a button doesn't quite fit the "hover over image".

Answer (score 2):

wxArtProvider may be able to help http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_art_provider.html

```
import wx
class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,msg,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(300,400))
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        staticIcon = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel, bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_WARNING), size=(32,32))
        mainSizer.Add(staticIcon, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        ttip = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n"
        ttip += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n"
        ttip += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n"
        ttip += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        staticIcon.SetToolTipString(ttip)
        buttonText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, msg, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        mainSizer.Add(buttonText, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        staticIcon.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, evt):
        print "The button was pressed - display some help"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Test(None, "Dummy Exercise", "Test 123")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nice, thanks. From a UX perspective it should either be a tooltip (i.e. hover) on an image OR a button the user is expected to click.